# \usepackage{newtxtext} gives Undefined control sequence with MacTeX

Tags: mactex

Can anyone help, I am trying to compile a resume with XeLatex and there are no spaces between words in the PDF. I have the latest version of MacTex and I have also tried on OverLeaf.

```
\pdfmapline{+dummy-space <dummy-space.pfb}
\pdfinterwordspaceon
```

do not work at all and just gives me: Undefined control sequence. Can anyone help?

Comment: those commands are pdftex commands they are not defined in xetex

Comment: newtxtext sets up a Times Roman clone with 8bit encodings for pdftex, just use an OpenType Times Roman or a clone such as TeX Gyre Termes when using xetex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but I don't think that xelatex can insert real space chars in the pdf regardless of the used font (wild guess that this is what the op wants)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well perhaps but using pdftex commands won't work anyway.